# In TypeOrm, what are the default fetch types for OneToMany and ManyToOne?

Tags: typeorm

Typeorm's official document states that if you use Lazy, you must use promise. If not promise, will default fetch type be eager loading? However, I checked and it seems to be loading Lazy, not Eager.
The default pitch type of JPA is as follows:

```
OneToMany: LAZY
ManyToOne: EAGER
ManyToMany: LAZY
OneToOne: EAGER
```

Is TypeOrm's default fetch type the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TLDR: **It is neither `lazy` nor `eager`**.

---

If you check [Typeorm relation options code](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/decorator/options/RelationOptions.ts#L56):

```js
export interface RelationOptions {
    ...

    /**
     * Set this relation to be lazy. Note: lazy relations are promises. When you call them they return promise
     * which resolve relation result then. If your property's type is Promise then this relation is set to lazy automatically.
     */
    lazy?: boolean;
    /**
     * Set this relation to be eager.
     * Eager relations are always loaded automatically when relation's owner entity is loaded using find* methods.
     * Only using QueryBuilder prevents loading eager relations.
     * Eager flag cannot be set from both sides of relation - you can eager load only one side of the relationship.
     */
    eager?: boolean;

    ...
}
```

You can see that Typeorm does not load the relation for any kind of relationship by default. Basically, it is neither `lazy` nor `eager`.

If you set neither `lazy` nor `eager`, it will not load the relationship at all unless you specified it in your `find` options, or in `QueryBuilder`.

See the below [example from Typeorm Documentation](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/find-options) for `find`:

```js
const user = userRepository.find({
    where: {
        name: "John",
    },
    relations: ["project"],
});

// Think user has a one-to-many relationship with projects, then:
// const projects = user.projects;
```

If you specify `lazy` or `eager` then you don't need to specify it in `find` options. But you will still have to specify the join condition when using `QueryBuilder`.

For `lazy`:

```js
const user = userRepository.find({
    where: {
        name: "John",
    }
});

// Need await for `lazy`:
// const projects = await user.projects;
```

For `eager`:

```js
const user = userRepository.find({
    where: {
        name: "John",
    }
});

// No await for `eager`:
// const projects = user.projects;
```

---

Hope this helps. Cheers  !!!

Comment: Thank you so much Heshan. I spent the day because of this problem. very very Thank you :)